# Find the value of $\int_0^1 P(x) dx $.

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, definite-integrals

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial of least degree whose graph has three points of inflection $(-1,-1),(1,1)$ and a third point with abscissa 0 , at which the tangent to the curve makes an angle of 60° with the positive x-axis.
Then find the value of $$\int_0^1 P(x) dx$$.

**My attempt** . As the points of inflection are at $x = 0,-1,1$ , it is clear that

$$P''(x) = ax(x+1)(x-1) = a(x^3 - x)$$, for some constant $a$.

And also given,$ P'(0)= \tan 60° = \sqrt 3$

Now , $$\int_0^x P''(x) dx = P'(x) - P'(0)$$ which on solving gives

$$P'(x) = a \left( {x^4 \over 4} - {x^2 \over 2} \right) + \sqrt 3 $$.

Beyond this , I have no idea how to solve this further . Any help would be appreciated , and also please do tell the basic theory behind this . Thank you .

Comment: Please do not use tags you do not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have more data available. Since
$$
P''(x)=a(x^3-x)
$$
you can integrate and get that
$$
P'(x)=\frac{a}{4}(x^4-2x^2)+b
$$
hence
$$
P(x)=\frac{a}{60}(3x^5-5x^3)+bx+c
$$
It's obviously better to start off again with $P''(x)=60a(x^3-x)$, so finally
$$
P(x)=a(3x^5-5x^3)+bx+c
$$
Now you know that $P(-1)=-1$ and $P(1)=1$, so
$$
2a-b+c=-1 \qquad -2a+b+c=1
$$
Thus $c=0$. Further you know that $P'(0)=\sqrt{3}$.

Now you should be able to finish.

Answer (score 1):

three points of inflexion means $P''=0$ has three solutions and so must be third order, we can say this gives us:
$$P''(x)=C_0x(x+1)(x-1)=C_0(x^3-x)$$
integrating we get:
$$P'(x)=C_1x^4-C_2x^2+C_3$$
as you said, we know:
$$P'(0)=\tan(60^o)=\sqrt{3}\Rightarrow C_3=\sqrt{3}$$
integrating again:
$$P(x)=K_1x^5-K_2x^2+\sqrt{3}x+K_4$$
now sub in values given:
$$P(-1)=-K_1-K_2-\sqrt{3}+K_4=-1$$
$$P(1)=K_1-K_2+\sqrt{3}+K_4=1$$
combine this with knowledge of 1st and 2nd derivates then solve for values of $K$, then the final step is just to integrate